# React, React-Router and setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, setinterval

I have a component whose state I wish to regularly update with a timing function, therefore I have the following code:

```
componentDidMount() {

    console.log("Stage.componentDidMount")

    // var self = this;
    if (this.timer == null) {
        console.log("create timer")

        var timerFunction = function() {
            console.log(this.timer);
        }.bind(this)

        this.timer = setInterval(timerFunction, 1000);  
    }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("component will unmount")
    clearInterval(this.timer)
}
```

The problem comes in when I refresh the route whose subcomponent is this subcomponent.  What I notice is that the parent of this component renders twice, and therefore this components constructor and componentDidMount is called twice.  This creates two timers, and my timing invocations of twice as numerous!

While this isn't a problem when just navigating to this route and then navigating away, as the componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount calls balance each other out, it is a problem when refreshing for the reason I described.

Is there some sort of balancing function or way to prevent the route's subcomponent (the one creating the timer in componentDidMount as shown in the code sample) from creating more than one timer?

Here is my root file, that setups of the routing and renders the "Renderer" which contains the subcomponent whose constructor is called twice.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './styles.css';

const NavLink = require( 'react-router-dom' ).NavLink

import Renderer from './renderer/Renderer'
import RootComponent from './componentsScratchPad/RootComponent'

function Nav() {    
        return (
            <ul className='nav'>
            <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to='/componentsScratchPad'>scratch pad</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink activeClassName="active" exact to='/renderer'>renderer</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
            )

}


class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
            <div>
            <Nav />
            <Route exact path='/renderer' render={ () => <Renderer /> } />
            <Route exact path="/componentsScratchPad" render={ () => <RootComponent /> }/>
            </div>
            </Router>
            )
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Can you post how you have configured your router?